# при любом запросе hibernate выдает ошибку

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea, hibernate

я заметил что при любой работе или вообще прикосновении к hibernate у меня выдает ошибку
мой код в java:

```
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import java.util.List;

public class Java {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().buildSessionFactory();
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(org.example.User.class);
        
            try {session.beginTransaction();
                Query query = (Query) session.createQuery("from User", User.class).list();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

    }
```

мой User:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name="user_data")
class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Integer id;

    @Column(name="user_name")
    public String name;

  
    @Column(name="user_level")
    public Integer level;

    @Column(name="user_created")
    public Date created;
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
    
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresDialect</property>
            <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
            <property name="connection.username">root</property>
            <property name="connection.password">password</property>
            <poperty name="hibernate.show_sql ">true</poperty>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
            <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    
             </session-factory>
            </hibernate-configuration>
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.29.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.3.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.log4jdbc/log4jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.log4jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.pluguins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-pluguin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.pluguins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-pluguin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.projectLombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                <version>1.18.26</version>
                            </path>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Ошибка:

```
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.15.Final
дек. 28, 2023 4:33:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
дек. 28, 2023 4:33:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746)
    at org.example.Java.main(Java.java:11)

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746)
    at org.example.Java.main(Java.java:11)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:272)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Ошибка содержит описание того, что произошло не так, поэтому прикладывайте её тоже.

Comment: Помимо указанного выше класс @Entity по требованиям должен содержать конструктор без аргументов.

Comment: В данном случае ошибка содержит текст `'hibernate.dialect' not set` и у вас в настройках его действительно нет (ошибка, написан просто `dialect` вместо `hibernate.dialect`). Так же указано неправильное значение, доступные значения находятся в пакете `org.hibernate.dialect` и [для версии 6.4.0](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html) будет `PostgreSQLDialect` (вместо `PostgresDialect`). Если будут другие ошибки, то вопросы задаются так же с их описанием. Как видно, в них обычно есть ответ на вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно проблема в

> property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresDialect</property

Где вместо 'dialect' должно быть 'hibernate.dialect'